# How to resolve: "Can not resolve all parameters for accueilComponent"

Tags: angular

I am developing an application with angular 6, in one of my components I import dependencies into the constructor.

I have this error :

```
Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for inscriptionComponent: (?, ?, ?).
    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for inscriptionComponent: (?, ?, ?).
       at syntaxError (eval code:11:1698) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getDependenciesMetadata (eval code:53:25919) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getTypeMetadata (eval code:53:22840) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (eval code:53:10846) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getEntryComponentMetadata (eval code:53:29218) [root>]
       at Anonymous function (eval code:53:28850) [root>]
       at Array.prototype.forEach (native code) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (eval code:53:28550) [root>]
       at Anonymous function (eval code:53:27725) [root>]
       at Array.prototype.forEach (native code) [root>]
       at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getProvidersMetadata (eval code:53:26403) [root>]
       at Anonymou
```

This is an error that has already been treated several times: ""
but I have not been able to solve my problem

my component :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { trucsAApprendreService } from '../../_trucsAApprendre.service';


@Component({
 selector: 'accueilComponent',
 templateUrl: `./app/memoreasy.module/accueil.component/accueil.component.html`,
 styleUrls: ['./app/memoreasy.module/accueil.component/accueil.component.css']
})
export class accueilComponent implements OnInit { 

 constructor(private router: Router, private trucsAApprendreService: trucsAApprendreService) {}

     }
```

I tried to remove one of my two dependencies to see if the error come from them but it does not work. If I import an dependencie I have this error

An idea ?

thank you in advance

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this for better understanding of question?

Comment: Can you check `inscriptionComponent` because the error seem to be coming from constructor of `inscriptionComponent`. If possible share its code as well

Comment: It looks like `inscriptionComponent` can't resolve one of the instances injected to its `constructor` you should check you have all of its services provided in the module which it declared in